# How to add or remove a button property

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

Suppose I have a simple button in my Vue.js template that calls a method like this:

```html
<q-btn label="login" @click="signIn" />
```

Once the method is finished I would like the button changed to this:

```html
<q-btn label="Bob" to="/settings" />
```

The issue is that it's not possible to combine `@click` with the `to` directive in one button.

In a case like this is it best to use `v-if="signedIn"` that triggers two different buttons (show `button a` if not signed in and else show `button b`)? Or is there a way to remove the `@click` event handler and replace it with the `to`?

What is the preferred way of handling this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend you approach with v-if because Vue will recognize that it is the same element and will only replace attributes and fragments of component that uses these propses/listeners.

You could do it on your own with by dynamically binding props & listeners with v-bind & v-on. But it does not make sense in this case.

This case is described here: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html#Controlling-Reusable-Elements-with-key

Comment: Thank you very much for the feedback. Indeed, it seem best to use `v-if` with its `key`.